SQL Server Case Then Statement
Is it possible to have multiple expression in the Then for a Case statement
What i want will look like this
Select EmployeeId,
Case 
 When Dateofjoin > '1-1-2000' Then Select Column1 , Select Column2, Select Column3
  ELSE Select Column5 , Select Column6, Select Column6
END CASE

from EmployeeTABLE


No, cannot use a case expression like that. I would just use UNION. Or, you could use multiple case expressions such as case when date > x then col1 else col4 end my_col1, case when date > x then col2 else col5 end my_col2 and so on

Why have you tagged both SQL Server 2008 and 2012? Are you really using both? Both are also completely unsupported, and have been for 5~ and 2~ years respectively; getting your upgrade path implemented is long overdue at this point.

Please learn how CASE works in the documentation.  You can't just do whatever you want, and expect it to work.

You can use separate case expressions for each column to return.
Select EmployeeId,
       case When Dateofjoin > '1-1-2000' Then Column1 else Column5 end,
       case When Dateofjoin > '1-1-2000' Then Column2 else Column6 end,
       case When Dateofjoin > '1-1-2000' Then Column3 else Column6 end
from EmployeeTABLE

Or do a UNION ALL:
Select EmployeeId, Column1, Column2, Column3
from EmployeeTABLE
where Dateofjoin > '1-1-2000'
UNION ALL
Select EmployeeId, Column5, Column6, Column6
from EmployeeTABLE
where Dateofjoin <= '1-1-2000'

If too slow, create a Dateofjoin index.

CASE expressions return scalar values, they can't return multiple columns.
Instead, I recommend using APPLY...
SELECT
  e.EmployeeId,
  c.*
FROM
  EmployeeTABLE   AS e
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    e.column1, e.column2, e.column3
  WHERE
    e.Dateofjoin >  '2000-01-01'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    e.column4, e.column5, e.column6
  WHERE
    e.Dateofjoin <= '2000-01-01'
)
  AS c

from EmployeeTABLE

No, you can't directly include multiple expressions in the THEN part of a CASE. But you can achieve something similar by separating the expressions into multiple CASE statements or by using subqueries.
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Dateofjoin > '2000-01-01' THEN (SELECT Column1 FROM EmployeeTABLE WHERE EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId)
    END AS Column1,
    CASE
        WHEN Dateofjoin > '2000-01-01' THEN (SELECT Column2 FROM EmployeeTABLE WHERE EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId)
    END AS Column2,
    CASE
        WHEN Dateofjoin > '2000-01-01' THEN (SELECT Column3 FROM EmployeeTABLE WHERE EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId)
    END AS Column3
FROM
    EmployeeTABLE;


This isn't an answer, it's a comment. An answer shows how to do the things you say will work.

This definitely won't work.
